# Class Extension Problem - RelatedObjectChanged not firing

Tags: arcobjects, classextensions

I'm trying to set up class extensions to have 3 feature classes communicate. I have feature classes A, B, and C. A has a simple, forward relationship with B, B has a simple, forward relationship with C. The goal is to have attribute updates in A force attribute updates in B, which in turn force attribute updates in C.

I have one class extension on feature class C that implements IRelatedObjectClassEvents2 RelatedObjectChanged, which listens for changes in feature class B. When I manually make an update to feature class B, as expected, the correct updates are made in feature class C. So that part is working.

Likewise, I have a class extension on feature class B that implements IRelatedObjectClassEvents2 RelatedObjectChanged, which listens for changes in feature class A. Also as expected, when I manually make updates to feature class A, the expected changes are made on feature class B. So this part is also working.

The problem I run into is that when I manually update Feature Class A, Feature Class B gets updated properly, but the extension on Feature Class C doesn't fire the RelatedObjectChanged event. As a result, my updates to feature class A aren't cascading all the way to feature class C.

What am I missing that is causing the event to not fire on feature class C?

Comment: would be very hard to figure out without any code samples i guess..

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't think of a way to post a condensed code block that would make sense to look at.  I guess I was just looking to see if their was a way to force feature class C to see that a change was made in feature class B.  I'm trying to explore ways to do this in feature class B's "OnChange" event.  Trying to somehow traverse the relationship to the destination class (feature class C) and call the RelatedObjectsChanged event manually.

I guess I was hoping someone could point me to some event handler I am missing or some sample code that has worked in the past and I could go from there.

Comment: Silly me.  I wasn't properly calling RelatedObject.Store() method in my RelatedObjectsChanged event for feature class B.  When testing in ArcMap, making a change to feature class A was updating the table for Feature Class B, but when I saved edits, the changes to B weren't saved.  With the Store() method properly working, the cascading updates are working.